# return reference to element of dynamic array in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is this is how you return a reference to an element of a dynamically allocated array with index i ??

```
    int& dynamic_array::operator[](unsigned int i) {
    if (i >= get_size())
        throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION);
    else
        return array[i];
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: To enable this to be used on `const` objects you'll need to add a `const` overload.  Also the `else` is redundant because `throw` aborts the flow of execution at that point.

Comment: Consider throwing [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) instead of `std::exception`.

Answer (score 0):

By trying to summerise in an elegant way the comments, you can use something like:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

int& dynamic_array::operator[](size_t index)
{
    if (index >= size)
        throw std::out_of_range{"Index too large " + std::to_string(index)};
    return elements[index];
}
```

a. size_t ensures 0 or positive index

b. out_of_range is the standard exception we except in these cases

c. the exception message is informative

If we want to go one mile further you usually need the const and the non-const version too. In order to avoid code duplication, you move like that:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

const int& dynamic_array::operator[](size_t index) const
{
    if (index >= size)
        throw std::out_of_range{"Index too large " + std::to_string(index)};
    return elements[index];
}

int& dynamic_array::operator[](size_t index)
{
    return const_cast<int&>(std::as_const(*this)[index]);
}
```

(std:as_const() belongs to C++17 otherwise consider static_cast<>)